# save button, save webpage as mht file (.net 4 vb)

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a website written in .net 4. I'd like to include a save button on one the pages that will save the webpage as a mht file. This way the user can save the page as a mht file type on his/her desktop without have to use the browser toolbar.

I'm currently working with the following code but I need to modify it so it to capture the url of the current page the user is viewing verses hard coding the url into the button click event. Thanks.

```
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SavePage("http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/default.aspx", "C:\msdn.mht")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SavePage(ByVal Url As String, ByVal FilePath As String)
        Dim iMessage As CDO.Message = New CDO.Message
        iMessage.CreateMHTMLBody(Url, _
        CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressNone, "", "")
        Dim adodbstream As ADODB.Stream = New ADODB.Stream
        adodbstream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeText
        adodbstream.Charset = "US-ASCII"
        adodbstream.Open()
        iMessage.DataSource.SaveToObject(adodbstream, "_Stream")
        adodbstream.SaveToFile(FilePath, _
                  ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to Add COM References to the 'Microsoft CDO For Windows 2000 Library' and 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library'. Then import them:

```
Imports ADODB
Imports CDO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SavePage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "C:\whatever.mht")
```

Comment: thanks, i'm getting the following error when i try to implement your code change: "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."